# php table : How to Embed Buttons To cell Values In php table row

Tags: php

I want to Embed buttons with cell values to The following rows [COL 3],[COL 4],[COL 5]

but my code gets underlined red, I want to know what I am doing wrong

here is my code:

```
            echo 
            
            '<tr><td>'. $row["COL 2"] . 
            
            '<td><input type='button' class='buttons' value ='. $row["COL 3"] .
            '<td><input type='button' class='buttons' value ='. $row["COL 3"] .
            '<td><input type='button' class='buttons' value ='. $row["COL 3"] .


            '<td>'. $row["COL 6"] .
            
            '</td></tr>',
```

Comment: As you can see by the colors, the `'` inside `'` needs to be escaped `\'` or use another qoutes `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `'` by using `\` before them, as you see below:

```
echo 
            
    '<tr><td>'. $row["COL 2"] . 
    '<td><input type=\'button\' class=\'buttons\' value =\''. $row["COL 3"] .'\' />
    ...
```

or you could change the html `'` by `"` as this sample:

```
           echo 
            
            '<tr><td>'. $row["COL 2"] . 
            
            '<td><input type="button" class="buttons" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .
            '" />'
     ...
```

As solicited by Ndeapos Silvanus, and based on his code, here is the 'whole' example:

```
echo             
    '<tr>
        <td>'. $row["COL 2"] .'</td> 
        <td><input type=\'button\' class=\'buttons\' value =\''. $row["COL 3"] .'\' /></td>
        <td><input type=\'button\' class=\'buttons\' value =\''. $row["COL 3"] .'\' /></td>
        <td><input type=\'button\' class=\'buttons\' value =\''. $row["COL 3"] .'\' /></td>
        <td><input type=\'button\' class=\'buttons\' value =\''. $row["COL 3"] .'\' /></td>
        <td><input type=\'button\' class=\'buttons\' value =\''. $row["COL 3"] .'\' /></td>
    </tr>';
```

or with double quotes

```
echo             
    '<tr>
        <td>'. $row["COL 2"] .'</td> 
        <td><input type="button" class="buttons" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="buttons" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="buttons" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="buttons" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="buttons" value ="'. $row["COL 3"] .'" /></td>
    </tr>';
```

Comment: Its still giving me red lines, can you please extend your code from COL 2 until COL 6 , i'm finding it difficult put them in the right places

Comment: @NdeapoSilvanus just updated the answer. Please review it and accept if it solves your doubt.

Comment: if I may Ask, I want to create a output cell that  sum all the selected values and show the total =, how do I do That??

Comment: @NdeapoSilvanus if I helped you, please mark the answer as correct and create a new question about the new issue.